# react mui-datatables, can't export only selected rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, jsx, mui-datatable

I'm using `"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2",`

I wonder if this library is customizable enough to work with, because currently I just want to export the rows of tables that are selected.

[image]

> I used the default download button of the library and also I added a
> custom button to allow the download of only selected table rows

```
const options = {
    ...  // other options
     onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, rows) => {
      console.log(rows); //  <-------- can't get only selected rows
    },
    customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData, setSelectedRows) => {
      return (
        <Box mr={4}>
          <Fab
            variant="extended"
            size="small"
            color="primary"
            aria-label="add"
            onClick={() => console.log(displayData)} // <--- can't get selected rows
          >
            <FileDownloadRounded />
            Exporter
          </Fab>
        </Box>
      );
    },

}
```

I used a customToolbarSelect and i tried to customize onDownload but i can't get only selected rows.

How can i correctly download only selected rows ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how you can retrieve records corresponding to selected rows in the toolbar context:

```
const options = {
...  // other options
 onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, rows) => {
  console.log(rows); //  <-------- can't get only selected rows
},
customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData, setSelectedRows) => {

  const handleClick = () => {
     const recordsToDownload = selectedRows?.data?.map(
         ({ index }) => displayData[index]
     ).map(
         ({ data }) => data
     );

    console.log('recordsToDownload', recordsToDownload);
  };

  return (
    <Box mr={4}>
      <Fab
        variant="extended"
        size="small"
        color="primary"
        aria-label="add"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <FileDownloadRounded />
        Exporter
      </Fab>
    </Box>
  );
},
```

Then you can use the **createCSVDownload** utility function to trigger CSV file download process: (https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/25e16b22cb146619d671fc2db8504aa98deddd0f/src/utils.js#L129)

The same function is used in the default toolbar: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/src/components/TableToolbar.js

Comment: thank you for your help , this task was done correctly using the same function